# Change Browser Capabilities through Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I do not have privileges to change IE settings locally. I wrote a Java Code to change the capabilities of IEDriver using :

```
 DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        caps.setCapability(
                InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                true);
```

I want to do the same thing while using the selenium webdriver in Robot Framework. I want to do something like this. But I do not know the right way to do it.

```
*** Keywords ***
Test Browser
    ${options}= Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER sys,selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS:True    
    Create WebDriver  Internet Explorer ie_options=${options}

Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}   
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Login Page Should Be Open
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

In the Selenium documentation for [DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#webdriver-1), the configurable properties are listed. The required property is ignoreProtectedModeSettings which must be set to True

```
${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER  sys, selenium.webdriver
Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ignoreProtectedModeSettings ${True}
Open Browser    www.google.com  ie  desired_capabilitie=${dc}

${s2l}= Get Library Instance    Selenium2Library
Log Dictionary  ${s2l._current_browser().capabilities}  # actual capabilities
```

Comment: Some description might help with better understand, for other user  :)

Comment: I hope the description ist now helpful.

Comment: This solution works in version IEDriverServer 3.4.0. When I tried v. 3.9.0 it ignores DesiredCapabilities and Capabilities stays as ignoreProtectedModeSettings: False

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that came here looking for a solution to [this problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=639) within Robot Framewor:

```
Set Chrome Desired Capabilities
    [Documentation]  Create the desired capabilities object with which to instantiate the Chrome browser.
    ${dc}                       Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.CHROME  sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${experimental_options}     Create Dictionary      useAutomationExtension   ${False}
    Set To Dictionary           ${dc}       chromeOptions   ${experimental_options}
    Set Global Variable         ${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}  ${dc}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation how it solves the problem, not only show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

As Pavol Travnik mentioned, David's answer no longer works. At some point the `ignoreProtectedModeSettings` key got placed inside the `se:ieOptions` dictionary within the capabilities dictionary. Here is code that will work with newer versions of the IEDriverServer:

```
${ie_dc} =      Evaluate  
    ...         sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER 
    ...         sys, selenium.webdriver
${ieOptions} =  Create Dictionary  ignoreProtectedModeSettings=${True}
Set To Dictionary   ${ie_dc}  se:ieOptions  ${ieOptions}
Open Browser    ${url}  ie  desired_capabilities=${ie_dc}
```

You can see this if you debug Selenium's Python library, specifically webdriver/remote/webdriver.py and look at the response in `start_session`.