# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error when setting Desired_capabilities in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, saucelabs

I am trying to set desired capabilities in my robot script and I am seeing the below error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I have tried the below options, the result is same- What am i missing here?

My Desired capabilities are:

```
${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES} =  name: Win 10 + Chrome 76, platform: Windows 10, browserName: chrome, version: 76.0
```

```
    Open Browser  ${START_URL}  ${BROWSER}
    ...  remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}
    ...  desired_capabilities=${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}
```

```
Open Browser  ${START_URL}  ${BROWSER}  remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}  desired_capabilities=${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}
```

Comment: I would add `selenium` tag here as it's the most relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

Desired capabilities should be a dictionary, not a string.

Take a look at a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058663/change-browser-capabilities-through-robot-framework).