# how to handle "your connection isn't private" for edge browser using robot framework

Tags: robotframework, microsoft-edge

```
${edgeOptions}  Create Dictionary   args    ${argument-list}    prefs   ${preferences}  binary  ${browser-file}

${desired_capabilities} Create Dictionary   platform    Windoof EdgeOptions ${EdgeOptions}  goog:edgeOptions    ${edgeOptions}

                    
${index}    Create Webdriver    Edge    executable_path=${browser-path}${/}msedgedriver.exe desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}    service_args=${serviceargs-list}
```

This isnt working , can someone help me to write desired capabilities for edge browser

Comment: What are desired capacilities for your case?

Comment: can you example what you want? what is your input?  expected output? what is the bugs or errors ?

Comment: I am currently trying to launch edge browser using robot framework . The browser is opening with my url , but it goes to the page where it promts this ssl error "your connection isn't private". onlywhen we click advance and ok we can login to page i am trying to access. i want to handle this in my robot kw , but facing error , its not ignoring the "your connection isn't private" message and proceeding

Comment: Are you using the new Edge based on Chromium? If so, you can refer to the Chrome solution and I think it should be the same with Edge Chromium. I found [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247155/selenium-interacting-with-your-connection-is-not-private) and you can try the accepted answer to add `--ignore-certificate-errors` and `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` options.

Comment: This way i need for edge - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058663/change-browser-capabilities-through-robot-framework

Comment: yes i am using on chromium , but the same solution we had for chrome is not woring on edge , we handled this in crome , but its not working in edge

Comment: How do you set it in Chrome? Have you tried using `--ignore-certificate-errors` option like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785694/how-to-resolve-ssl-certificate-errors-for-test-automation-in-robot-framework) and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490989/ignore-or-resolve-certificate-warnings-for-test-automation-in-robot-framework)? Besides, try to use `use_chromium=True` in edge options. For more information, you can refer to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python#use-chromium-specific-options).