# Robot Framework with edge browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, microsoft-edge

i have installed msedge browser 88.0.705 version.

i am able to launch browser but security certificate appears once the browser gets launch. This was handled for chrome in the below way. Can someone please help me how to handle this for edge browser.

```
[Arguments]    ${URL}
${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method     ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage


Run Keyword If    os.sep == '/'    Create Webdriver    Chrome    my_alias    chrome_options=${chrome_options}    executable_path=/selenium_drivers/chromedriver
...    ELSE    Create Webdriver    Chrome    my_alias    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
```

Please help with code for edge browser.I Tried in the similar manner but it doesn't work with edge

Comment: It seems that there're many similar issues, like [this thread](https://forum.robotframework.org/t/chromium-arguments-not-taken-by-edge-browser/439) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741171/how-to-handle-your-connection-isnt-private-for-edge-browser-using-robot-frame). But I didn't find there's any solution about this. I think the issue might be related with robot framework, I suggest that you can raise an issue in [robot framework github](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues) to see if they can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions
or
Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].chrome.options.Options
chromedriver,            geckodriver,              operadriver  
chrome.options.Options   firefox.options.Options   opera.options.Options

msedgedriver        edge.options.Options does not exist
msedgedriver supports DesiredCapabilities but not Options
edge.webdriver.DesiredCapabilites
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).